# Where I can find the directory of my Datomic distribution?

Tags: database, clojure, datomic

Where I can find the directory of my Datomic distribution?

I've installed Datomic via brew and now I'm trying to install the Datomic console but I can't find the Datomic distribution directory.

Comment: This gets some few candidates on my Linux machine: `sudo find / -name "datomic-pro*" -type d`.

Comment: Is this really related to anything else but [brew]?  e.g. does this solve your problem: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145437/where-can-i-find-the-installed-package-path-via-brew

Answer (score 1):

For the datomic-pro the datomic directory is the one that the .zip file was unziped:

for:

`./datomic-pro-0.9.5561.50.zip`

it is:

`./datomic-pro-0.9.5561.50`

and you can open the console with:

`./datomic-pro-0.9.5561.50/bin/console -p 8080 alias datomic-transactor-pro-0.9.5561.50.jar`

for brew I'm still not sure because things get spread around the file system like this:

```
prop-dir=/usr/local/etc/datomic/free-transactor.properties
data-dir=/usr/local/var/lib/datomic/
log-dir=/usr/local/var/lib/datomic/log
```